# Comments in BibTex

Tags: bibtex, comments

Basic question (though I haven't found it here):

How do I comment out parts (some lines within an entry which I would like to save for later) of a `BibTex` file?

Apparently, `@` can be used to comment out lines (but not be used within a comment itself), but only outside an entry, you have to move the commented lines out of the entry they belong to). Is there any other way?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93972/comment-out-sections-of-text-in-bib-file

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can "comment" whole entries by erasing the `@` in front of the type declaration (`@book -> book`); there are no other ways of commenting parts of entries. However, unknown fields are ignored, so you can say

```
OPTpages={34--35},
```

in order to ignore the `pages` field. Also repeated fields are ignored.

---

As a matter of fact, text between entries will be ignored, which is why the above works; only what appears between the braces like in

```
@ENTRY{...
  ...
}
```

is considered. However, it should be noted that Biber is stricter than BibTeX in this respect, so it will warn about what it considers junk between entries. Adding a `%` at the beginning of a line turns off Biber's warnings.

Comment: Good. Now '//' before a line is treated as commented out.

Comment: For me, using `//` with TeXstudio and biber puts it into a never ending compile loop.  However, I can put `%` before a line and it won't appear in the bibliography, [see this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93982/17916), but unfortunately TeXstudio's color highlighting won't make it grey out like a comment.

Answer (score 20):

Emacs uses the prefix '@Comment' when using the "comment-or-uncomment-region" command in a BibTex file.  This works on any line (at least in my version).

Using '%' also works for me, but I remember having it not work once -- I guess it may not be the most compatible.

Otherwise, you can achieve a similar effect to commenting out by changing the strings:  (1) Change the key of a whole bibtex entry to something else, or (2) change the name of a BibTex field, as BibTex ignores field it doesn't know.  In particular, I often "comment out" fields by prepending an underscore to the field name, e.g., I include

_pages = { TODO },

to mark that I should add the page number later.

Comment: Yeah, I put "comments" with `%` in bibtex in Overleaf, and they were coloured gray. However, I started getting errors from "commented out entries". So `% - comments` work great outside entries.

Comment: I have done something like this - 
@article{....
year = "2018",
Comment ="not important- you can delete this citation"}