# Comment out sections of text in bib file

Tags: biblatex, biber, comments

What's the correct way to comment out sections of explanatory text (included for humans to read) in a .bib file? I would like biber/biblatex to simply ignore this text.

When I put in text like

```
#######################################################################
## PREPRINTS
```

I get warnings like

```
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/8XsEEmjVOo/bib-latest.bib_14175.utf8, line 7, warning: 139 characters of junk seen at toplevel
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Anything that is not inside a recognized entry is a comment. So just type along! Any `.bib` interpreter that complains about it is buggy, as it is not following the rules laid down in [btxdoc](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxdoc.pdf). However, you can use an entry like `@COMMENT`, which will hopefully not trigger any complains.

Comment: See addition to question.

Comment: So Biber does not discard this stuff, whereas BibTeX does, whereas Biber respects `%`, whereas BibTeX does not?

Comment: @cfr I think you are correct. a bit messy really. but personally I prefer biber's behaviour as it is basically what you would expect from a tex file and more flexible.

Comment: @ArTourter But it still spews warnings about it all, which TeX wouldn't. It's a comment - why does Biber tell me it's junk?

Comment: @cfr, what do you mean? Are you saying that biber is spewing warnings when you use the `%` comment syntax or the `@COMMENT` one? It doesn't say anything for me about the `%` and I used these things all over the place.

Comment: @cfr, actually I just tried to have a `@COMMENT{}` entry in my bib file and biber (version 2.11, from texlive 2018) didn't complain at all.

Comment: @ArTourter I use `%` and it spews warnings all the time. I know I can ignore them, but it is a pain as they clutter the output.

Comment: @cfr can you give me an mwe for something that spew out warnings? as I can't reproduce at all... also may this conversation might be better off in a chat

Comment: @ArTourter Sorry. I think I'm just wrong. I can't reproduce it either. I was sure this was the reason I get all those junk warnings, but maybe it isn't. Probably something else. Apologies for the wild goose chase.

Answer (score 42):

At least with `biber`, you should be able to use the same commenting method as with LaTeX, that is using `%` for the commented line.

After a few test comments can be outside entries, within entries (commenting a whole line) or commenting the end of a line.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%
% PREPRINT
@article{myarticle,
    author = {Onymous, A. N.}, %The author
    % the title of the article
    title = {A Nice title},
}
```

Should work as expected. However this may not be the case with `bibtex`.

Comment: Re: "However this may not be the case with `bibtex`". Indeed, this does not seem to work with `bibtex`. I have an entry in my `.bib` file with a line like `author = {Onymous, A. N.}, %The author` in it. In TeXShop, when I hit the Typeset button with BibTex selected in the drop down next to it, I get a message in the console saying "You're missing a field name" and "I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry". The rest of my entry was indeed ignored and I got an incomplete reference in my `.pdf`.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom no but the question was about biber/biblatex. I never claimed that this solution would work with bibtex.

Comment: yes, you are right. I felt it was worth investigating, but now that I realise the question is probably about alternatives to `bibtex`, I realise my comment is probably not so useful. I'm quite a novice at these things, do you think mine is a case of a buggy `.bib` interpreter, as the other answer suggests? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 21):

I had difficulties commenting out entries in a .bib file (as opposed to adding free-standing comments). Posts to date on this thread did not address this particular problem.

I'm using [`Overleaf`](https://www.overleaf.com/)). What I observed:

- `bibtex` looks for entries (`@blah`) **before** it checks if the line starts with a `%` (or so I figured).
- but **only** that line gets processed; if you commented out the entire entry the rest of it (`title=`, etc) is ignored and you end up with errors ('missing field') attributable to `@blah`

Sheesh.

This doesn't work:

```
%@article{foo2019,
% ...
% }
```

This works (replace the `@`):

```
%%article{foo2019,
% ...
% }
```

I poked around in `Overleaf` and found [this](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/532-creating-and-managing-bibliographies-with-bibtex-on-overleaf) explanation (note that mine, above, is a bit different):

> % is actually not a comment character in .bib files! So, inserting a %
>   in .bib files not only fails to comment out the line, it also causes
>   some BibTEX errors. To get BibTEX to ignore a particular field we just
>   need to rename the field to something that BibTEX doesn’t recognise.
>   For example, if you want to keep a date field around but prefer that
>   it’s ignored (perhaps because you want BibTEX to use the year field
>   instead) write Tdate = {...} or the more human-readable IGNOREdate =
>   {...}.
>
> To get BibTEX to ignore an entire entry you can remove the @ before
>   the entry type. A valid reference entry always starts with a @
>   followed by the entry type; without the @ character BibTEX skips the
>   lines until it encounters another @.

`bibtex` is very focused on `@`; `biber` apparently respects `%`s (but you'd have to use `biblatex`). See pointers provided by [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) (in the comments) for other discussion.

Comment: Note that there is a difference in behaviour between Biber (`btparse`) and BibTeX. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261261/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325696/35864.

Comment: Thank you Kurt & moewe. I looked into things a bit more carefully and amended the post. When you search for a particular problem you typically get a bunch of hits. If you're lucky you click on the right one. Sometimes you don't.