# Adding specific citation creates error message

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am quite new to Latex. Using citations works well until I add a specific one. After adding this citation (with: `\autocite{Yamashita:2000a}` this error occurs:

```
    Runaway argument?
{We isolated mouse cDNA encoding a novel FGF (251 amino acids). As th\ETC.
./XYZ.tex:13: File ended while scanning use
 of \field.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \begin{document}
```

Related entry:

```
@article{Yamashita:2000aa,
Abstract = {We isolated mouse cDNA encoding a novel FGF (251 amino acids). As this is the 23rd documented FGF, we termed it FGF-23. FGF-23 has a hydrophobic amino terminus ( approximately 24 amino acids), which is a typical signal sequence. As expected, recombinant mouse FGF-23 was efficiently secreted by High Five insect cell-infected recombinant baculovirus containing the cDNA, indicating that FGF-23 is a secreted protein. We also isolated human cDNA encoding FGF-23 (251 amino acids), which is highly identical ( approximately 72% amino acid identity) to mouse FGF-23. Of human FGF family members, FGF-23 is most similar to FGF-21 and FGF-19 ( approximately 24% and approximately 22% amino acid identities, respectively). Human FGF-23 gene was localized on the chromosome 12p13 and found to be tandem linked (within 5.5 kb) to human FGF-6 gene. The expression of FGF-23 mRNA in mouse adult tissues was examined by real-time quantitative polymerase chain reaction. FGF-23 mRNA was mainly expressed in the brain and thymus at low levels. The localization of FGF-23 mRNA in the brain was examined by in situ hybridization. FGF-23 mRNA in the brain was found to be preferentially expressed in the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus. Therefore, FGF-23 is expected a unique FGF that plays roles in the function of the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus.},
Author = {Yamashita, T and Yoshioka, M and Itoh, N},
Date-Added = {2014-09-17 10:13:53 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-09-17 10:13:53 +0000},
Doi = {10.1006/bbrc.2000.3696},
Journal = {Biochem Biophys Res Commun},
Journal-Full = {Biochemical and biophysical research communications},
Mesh = {Amino Acid Sequence; Animals; Baculoviridae; Blotting, Western; Brain; Cell Line; Chromosome Mapping; Chromosomes, Human, Pair 12; DNA, Complementary; Electrophoresis, Polyacrylamide Gel; Fibroblast Growth Factors; Humans; In Situ Hybridization; Mice; Molecular Sequence Data; Phylogeny; RNA, Complementary; RNA, Messenger; Recombinant Proteins; Sequence Homology, Amino Acid; Tissue Distribution; Ventral Thalamic Nuclei},
Month = {Oct},
Number = {2},
Pages = {494-8},
Pmid = {11032749},
Pst = {ppublish},
Title = {Identification of a novel fibroblast growth factor, FGF-23, preferentially expressed in the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus of the brain},
Volume = {277},
Year = {2000},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/bbrc.2000.3696},
Bdsk-File-1 = {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}}
```

I would appreciacte some help.
Thank you!

/edit:
Sorry for that! Of course.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\bibliography{FGF23BIB}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\begin{document}

\author{XYZ}
\title{XYZ}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Text}
\subsection{Text}
Text \autocite{Stubbs:2007aa}
Text 2 \autocite{Yamashita:2000aa}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The first citation (\autocite{Stubbs:2007aa}) works without any problems. As soon as I add the second the previous error occurs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the abstract field?

Comment: There is a `%` in the abstract field, try replacing that with `\%`. Or removing the field altogether, as @U.Martinez-Corral suggests.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, you should not use `%` in the `abstract` field. Either escape those replacing them with `\%`:

```
@article{Yamashita:2000aa,
Abstract = {We isolated mouse cDNA encoding a novel FGF (251 amino acids). As this is the 23rd documented FGF, we termed it FGF-23. FGF-23 has a hydrophobic amino terminus ( approximately 24 amino acids), which is a typical signal sequence. As expected, recombinant mouse FGF-23 was efficiently secreted by High Five insect cell-infected recombinant baculovirus containing the cDNA, indicating that FGF-23 is a secreted protein. We also isolated human cDNA encoding FGF-23 (251 amino acids), which is highly identical ( approximately 72\% amino acid identity) to mouse FGF-23. Of human FGF family members, FGF-23 is most similar to FGF-21 and FGF-19 ( approximately 24\% and approximately 22\% amino acid identities, respectively). Human FGF-23 gene was localized on the chromosome 12p13 and found to be tandem linked (within 5.5 kb) to human FGF-6 gene. The expression of FGF-23 mRNA in mouse adult tissues was examined by real-time quantitative polymerase chain reaction. FGF-23 mRNA was mainly expressed in the brain and thymus at low levels. The localization of FGF-23 mRNA in the brain was examined by in situ hybridization. FGF-23 mRNA in the brain was found to be preferentially expressed in the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus. Therefore, FGF-23 is expected a unique FGF that plays roles in the function of the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus.},
Author = {Yamashita, T and Yoshioka, M and Itoh, N},
Date-Added = {2014-09-17 10:13:53 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-09-17 10:13:53 +0000},
Doi = {10.1006/bbrc.2000.3696},
Journal = {Biochem Biophys Res Commun},
Journal-Full = {Biochemical and biophysical research communications},
Mesh = {Amino Acid Sequence; Animals; Baculoviridae; Blotting, Western; Brain; Cell Line; Chromosome Mapping; Chromosomes, Human, Pair 12; DNA, Complementary; Electrophoresis, Polyacrylamide Gel; Fibroblast Growth Factors; Humans; In Situ Hybridization; Mice; Molecular Sequence Data; Phylogeny; RNA, Complementary; RNA, Messenger; Recombinant Proteins; Sequence Homology, Amino Acid; Tissue Distribution; Ventral Thalamic Nuclei},
Month = {Oct},
Number = {2},
Pages = {494-8},
Pmid = {11032749},
Pst = {ppublish},
Title = {Identification of a novel fibroblast growth factor, FGF-23, preferentially     expressed in the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus of the brain},
Volume = {277},
Year = {2000},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/bbrc.2000.3696},
Bdsk-File-1 = {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}}
}
```

or, since you are using `biblatex`, just [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93972/comment-out-sections-of-text-in-bib-file) the whole field using some undefined field, e.g. `COMMENTAbstract`:

```
@article{Yamashita:2000aa,
COMMENTAbstract = {We isolated mouse cDNA encoding a novel FGF (251 amino acids). As this is the 23rd documented FGF, we termed it FGF-23. FGF-23 has a hydrophobic amino terminus ( approximately 24 amino acids), which is a typical signal sequence. As expected, recombinant mouse FGF-23 was efficiently secreted by High Five insect cell-infected recombinant baculovirus containing the cDNA, indicating that FGF-23 is a secreted protein. We also isolated human cDNA encoding FGF-23 (251 amino acids), which is highly identical ( approximately 72\% amino acid identity) to mouse FGF-23. Of human FGF family members, FGF-23 is most similar to FGF-21 and FGF-19 ( approximately 24\% and approximately 22\% amino acid identities, respectively). Human FGF-23 gene was localized on the chromosome 12p13 and found to be tandem linked (within 5.5 kb) to human FGF-6 gene. The expression of FGF-23 mRNA in mouse adult tissues was examined by real-time quantitative polymerase chain reaction. FGF-23 mRNA was mainly expressed in the brain and thymus at low levels. The localization of FGF-23 mRNA in the brain was examined by in situ hybridization. FGF-23 mRNA in the brain was found to be preferentially expressed in the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus. Therefore, FGF-23 is expected a unique FGF that plays roles in the function of the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus.},
Author = {Yamashita, T and Yoshioka, M and Itoh, N},
Date-Added = {2014-09-17 10:13:53 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-09-17 10:13:53 +0000},
Doi = {10.1006/bbrc.2000.3696},
Journal = {Biochem Biophys Res Commun},
Journal-Full = {Biochemical and biophysical research communications},
Mesh = {Amino Acid Sequence; Animals; Baculoviridae; Blotting, Western; Brain; Cell Line; Chromosome Mapping; Chromosomes, Human, Pair 12; DNA, Complementary; Electrophoresis, Polyacrylamide Gel; Fibroblast Growth Factors; Humans; In Situ Hybridization; Mice; Molecular Sequence Data; Phylogeny; RNA, Complementary; RNA, Messenger; Recombinant Proteins; Sequence Homology, Amino Acid; Tissue Distribution; Ventral Thalamic Nuclei},
Month = {Oct},
Number = {2},
Pages = {494-8},
Pmid = {11032749},
Pst = {ppublish},
Title = {Identification of a novel fibroblast growth factor, FGF-23, preferentially     expressed in the ventrolateral thalamic nucleus of the brain},
Volume = {277},
Year = {2000},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/bbrc.2000.3696},
Bdsk-File-1 = {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}}
}
```

Comment: `%` is not a comment character in `.bib` files; if you want to “comment out“ a field, change its name to an undefined one, like `COMMENTAbstract = {...}`

Comment: I suppose using `%abstract` also worked just because it is not a defined field. Anyway, I've edited to make it clear.