# How can I suppress "retrieved [date] from [URL]" in the bibliography using apacite in overleaf?

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I am  using the apacite package, and it is printing references like this:

> Vicary, S., Sperling, M., von Zimmermann, J., Richardson, D. C., & Orgs, G. (2017,
> July). Joint action aesthetics. PLOS ONE , 12 (7), e0180101. Retrieved 2021-02-
> 07, from https://dx.plos.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0180101 doi: 10.1371/jour-
> nal.pone.0180101

I want to suppress printing "Retrieved [date] from [URL]", but keep the doi -- like this:

> Vicary, S., Sperling, M., von Zimmermann, J., Richardson, D. C., & Orgs, G. (2017,
> July). Joint action aesthetics. PLOS ONE , 12 (7), e0180101. doi: 10.1371/jour-
> nal.pone.0180101

I have tried commenting out the url line in the bib file, but that breaks the bibliography and causes many other fields not to print as well. That same reference ends up printing like this:

> Joint action aesthetics. (n.d.). , 12

How can I suppress the Retrieved from URL information in the bibliography using apacite? I am using overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the bib entry in question, and please clarify what "I have tried commenting out the url line in the bib file" actually entailed.

Comment: Biblatex with biber have options to filter out fields we don’t want to appear. It’s in the Dynamic Modification of Data in CTAN Biblatex. One sample of using such filters can be found [here](https://www.semipol.de/posts/2018/06/latex-best-practices-lessons-learned-from-writing-a-phd-thesis/#citations)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Alex Rudnicky to this question (link below) solved my problem. TL;DR Bib files don't recognize the % sign. But if you rename the field to something that BibTEX doesn't recognize then it will ignore that field.

[Comment out sections of text in bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93972/comment-out-sections-of-text-in-bib-file)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [this online tool called *bibtex tidy*](https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy/) for cleaning the BibTeX files. Besides a lot of useful cleanings and formatting options, there is also the option to remove certain fields, i.e., `retrieved` in your case.

[image]