# bibtex comment out lines

Tags: bibtex, comments

I have a bibtex file contains the following line:

```
@inproceedings{Cai03,
author = {Cai, Deng and Yu, Shipeng and Wen, Ji-Rong and Ma, Wei-Ying},
title = {Extracting Content Structure for Web Pages Based on Visual Representation},
% booktitle = {Proceedings of the 5th Asia-Pacific Web Conference on Web Technologies and Applications},
series = {APWeb'03},
year = {2003},
% isbn = {3-540-02354-2},
% location = {Xian, China},
pages = {406--417},
% numpages = {12},
% url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1766091.1766143},
% acmid = {1766143},
% publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
% address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
}
```

It can only display the `author` and `title` of the paper after texified. So I am wondering how to also display `series`, `year` and `pages`.

Comment: You have to find a bibtex style (bet) that include the information in the field. Alternatively, you can use `biblatex` and you can more easily customise the way bibliographic entries are formatted and what information is include in them. Depending on the `bst` style you use the `year/page/series` information is removed if there is no `booktitle`. What you wan there is to use the value of series for book title. By the way ApWeb'03 is the acronym of the conference and the proper series would be LNCS.

Comment: please provide a minimal working example reproducing the problem.

Comment: See [Comments in BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/) The percent sign is *not* a comment character in `.bib` files end you get errors when running BibTeX on that entry. If you want to comment a field, you need to use a nonstandard name; for instance, `address` can be modified into `OPTaddress`.