# Biblatex adding fields to IEEE style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have the following example:

```
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=ieee,
bibencoding=ascii
backref=true
hyperref=true
% style=alphabetic
% style=reading
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibilography.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{carl_venture}    

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the bibilography.bib:

```
@book{carl_venture,
    keywords = {call},
    author    = "Carl Venture",
    title     = "The adventures of Carl Venture.",
    publisher = "C.V.",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    edition  = "3",
    year      = "1999",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
```

I get this:

> [#] Carl Venture, The adventures of Carl Venture. C.V.

It is missing the year and edition. How can I enable this fields in the bibliography without changing the IEEE styles?

Comment: I've tried your example and, as is, I couldn't build it. But adding `documentclass` and removing the commented fields in your bib entry, it worked, including year and edition. See, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21709/105447 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261261/105447.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this worked. Thank you @gusbrs. So one has to be careful to not have commented lines in .bib.

Comment: @gusbrs if you can, please answer to get the credits. Thank you.

Comment: Focha, I believe moewe meant that as a friendly reminder. You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to understand why he did it, and how the site "rewards" those who participate. But, you can keep the advice for the next time. For this particular question, once you answered it, it would be fine if you accepted your own answer, it's no big deal.

Comment: Copy. That you @gusbrs . I'll do it next time. Thank you guys and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of gusbrs, the only thing I did, was what he/she recommended, I eliminate the commented lines and it worked without any problem.

So be careful with the commented lines in .bib file.

Comment: Ideally you would ask the person that actually found the answer and suggested it in the comments to write an answer for your question. That way you can award credit where credit is due. It is no way frowned upon to write an answer to your own question, but if someone else actually suggested the answer, you might as well ask the to write it down.

Comment: Note that % is NOT a comment character in bibtex, so technically you had malformed bibtex file.

Comment: @moewe I think I credit him in the answer. I am sorry, but I did it so others could see that it was answered already. Also, I don't understand why not answer instead of reply to the question. He is free to answer, and credit will be due to him, I am sure. Your opinion is taken into account, next time I'll do that for sure. Thank you.

Comment: @Aditya I think I copied and pasted directly from the documentation, and I thought that % could also be read as comments in .bib file. Thank you.

Comment: Some people reply in the comments with a suggestion if they can't test their solutions. See also [Why do people answer in comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/35864) The question did not provide a full MWE, and the `.bib` entry misses the closing brace. It is not immediately clear whether that was just a typo or an integral part of the problem. When I was talking about 'credit' above I was not only talking about the idea of attribution I was also thinking about the more 'tangible' credit of up-voting and accepting answers.