# Blank First Entry [1] in Bibtex-made Bibliography

Tags: bibtex

My problem is as title. The first entry is my Bibliography is simply empty/blank, and obviously, I do not have an empty item in my `bibtex` file.

(This is where I want to show the screenshot of the problem and I am NOT ALLOWED to post more than 2 links ...)

I am completely new to using LaTeX, and I dont know what information is needed to troubleshoot, so ask away.

I am using TeXStudio and here are the packages in my main file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

I'm just going to go ahead and link my [main file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BycqC6_l9vZKVzJkSVQ5MnRicGc) and [bibtex](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BycqC6_l9vZKN2drZFNwWHpsaGM) file, because they are too long to print here.

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case the cause was that commenting out code with % doesn't work as expected in bibtex: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335678/198146

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have some missing commas in your bib file. They are causing your first empty entry.

Please check the following bib entrys for missing commas:

```
@article{cyclotron,
@article{Schmidt2005,
@article{inversebrems,
@misc{reddening
```

The following not so small MWE compiles without errors:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{meus,
    title={Private Communications},
    author={Meusinger, Helmut},
    year={2017},
}


% Introduction

@article{meus2012aspect,
    title={{ASPECT}: A spectra clustering tool for exploration of large spectral surveys},
    author={Meusinger, Helmut and Schalldach, PF and Newholm, Mark and others},
    journal={Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
    volume={547},
    pages={A115},
    year={2012},
    publisher={EDP Sciences},
}


@article{abazajian2009seventh,
    title={The seventh data release of the Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    author={Abazajian, Kevork N and Adelman-McCarthy, Jennifer K and Ag{\"u}eros, Marcel A and Allam, Sahar S and Prieto, Carlos Allende and An, Deokkeun and Anderson, Kurt SJ and Anderson, Scott F and Annis, James and Bahcall, Neta A and others},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series},
    volume={182},
    number={2},
    pages={543},
    year={2009},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}

@incollection{kalomeni2005,
    title={Flickering in the magnetic CV star AM Herculis},
    author={Kalomeni, Belinda and Pek{\"U}nl{\"U}, E Rennan and Yakut, Kadri},
    booktitle={Zden{\v{e}}k Kopal’s Binary Star Legacy},
    pages={477--480},
    year={2005},
    publisher={Springer},
}

@misc{SDSSdr13,
    title = {{SDSS} Data Release 13},
    author={Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    note = {\url{http://www.sdss.org/}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-04-30},
}

@misc{aspect,
    title = {{ASPECT} - A SPEctra Clustering Tool},
    author={Meusinger, Helmut},
    note={\url{http://www.tls-tautenburg.de/TLS/fileadmin/forschung/meus/ASPECT/ASPECT.html}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-04-30},
}

% Background
% M star, HR diagrem

@misc{colorstars,
    title = {The Colour of Stars},
    author={Australia Telescope National Facility},
    note={\url{http://www.atnf.csiro.au/outreach/education/senior/astrophysics/photometry_colour.html}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-07-30},
}

@article{starrysky,
    title={The Real Starry Sky},
    author={Ledrew, Glenn},
    url={http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001JRASC..95...32L},
    journal={Journal of the Royal Astronomical Society of Canada},
    Volume={95},
    Page={32},
    year={Feb 2001},
}

@article{exoplanet,
    title={Exoplanets near red dwarfs suggest another Earth nearer},
    author={Jason Palmer},
    url={http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-21350899},
    journal={BBC News},
    year={Feb 2013},
}

@article{engle2011red,
    title={Red dwarf stars: ages, rotation, magnetic dynamo activity and the habitability of hosted planets},
    author={Engle, Scott G and Guinan, Edward F},
    journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1111.2872},
    year={2011},
}

@misc{evolowmass,
    title={Late stages of evolution for low-mass stars},
    author={Michael Richmond},
    publisher={Rochester Institute of Technology},
    year={November 10, 2004},
    note={\url{http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys230/lectures/planneb/planneb.html}},
}

@article{adams1997dying,
    title={A dying universe: the long-term fate and evolutionof astrophysical objects},
    author={Adams, Fred C and Laughlin, Gregory},
    journal={Reviews of Modern Physics},
    volume={69},
    number={2},
    pages={337},
    year={1997},
    publisher={APS},
}

@article{kaltenegger2009transits,
    title={Transits of Earth-like planets},
    author={Kaltenegger, Lisa and Traub, Wesley A},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
    volume={698},
    number={1},
    pages={519},
    year={2009},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}

%polar

@article{cropper1990polars,
    title={The polars},
    author={Cropper, Mark},
    journal={Space Science Reviews},
    volume={54},
    number={3-4},
    pages={195--295},
    year={1990},
    publisher={Springer},
}


@article{AMHerculis,
    title={The Three-dimensional Structure of Extreme-Ultraviolet Accretion Regions in AM Herculis Stars: Modeling of Extreme-Ultraviolet Photometric and Spectroscopic Observations},
    author={Martin M. Sirk and Steve B. Howell},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
    volume={506},
    pages={824-841},
    year={1998 Oct 20},
    publisher={The American Astronomical Society},
}

@article{cyclotron,
    title={Single-electron cyclotron radiation},
    author={Ben Monreal},
    journal={Physics Today},
    volume={69},
    number={1},
    pages={70},
    year={Jan 2016},
    publisher={AIP Publishing},
    url={http://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/PT.3.3060},
}

@article{Schmidt2005,
    title={NEW LOW ACCRETION RATE MAGNETIC BINARY SYSTEMS AND THEIR SIGNIFICANCE
    FOR THE EVOLUTION OF CATACLYSMIC VARIABLES},
    author={Gary D. Schmidt},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
    volume={630},
    pages={1037-1053},
    year={Sept 2005},
    publisher={The American Astronomical Society},
    url={http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/431969/pdf},
}

@article{Ferrario2015,
    title={Magnetic white dwarfs},
    author={Ferrario, Lilia and de Martino, Domitilla and G{\"a}nsicke, Boris T},
    journal={Space Science Reviews},
    volume={191},
    number={1-4},
    pages={111--169},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Springer},
}

@article{Cropper,
    title={The magnetic field in four AM Her systems:
    measurements from cyclotron humps},
    author={Mark Cropper},
    journal={Royal Astronomical Society},
    volume={236},
    pages={29-38},
    year={1988},
}

%bremsstrahlung
@article{inversebrems,
    title={Inverse Bremsstrahlung In Shocked Astrophysical Plasmas},
    author={Matthew G. Baring, Frank C. Jones},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
    volume={528},
    pages={776-788},
    year={2000 January 10},
    publisher={Laboratory for High Energy Astrophysics},
    url={http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/308194/pdf},
}

@article{Brems-jeff,
    title={The Bremsstrahlung, Synchrotron and Compton effects
    as emission processes in Astrophysics},
    author={Jeff Stanger},
    note={\url{http://www.jeffstanger.net/Astronomy/emissionprocesses.html}},
}

@misc{bremslecture,
    title = {Lecture 3 : Accelerated charges and bremsstrahlung},
    author={Chris Flynn},
    publisher={Swinburne University},
    year={2006},
    note={\url{http://www.astro.utu.fi/~cflynn/astroII/l3.html}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-04-30},
}

%reddening

@book{whittet2003dust,
    title={Dust in the Galactic Environment, 2nd edn., Series on Astronomy and Astrophysics},
    author={Whittet, Doug CB},
    publisher={Philadelphia: Institute of Physics Publishing},
    year={2003},
}

@misc{reddening,
    title={Interstellar Reddening, Extinction, and Red Sunsets},
    author={University of Virginia},
    year={2002},
}

% Data

@article{SDSSfilespec,
    title = {{SDSS} Data File Specifications},
    author={Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    note={\url{https://data.sdss.org/datamodel/files/BOSS_SPECTRO_REDUX/RUN2D/spectra/PLATE4/spec.html}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-07-30},
}

@article{boss,
    title = {{SDSS} {BOSS} Spectrograph},
    author={Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    note={\url{http://www.sdss.org/instruments/boss_spectrograph/}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-07-30},
}

@misc{SDSSdr7,
    title = {{SDSS} Data Release 7},
    author={Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    note={\url{http://classic.sdss.org/dr7/}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-07-30},
}
@misc{SDSSdr12,
    title = {{SDSS} Data Release 12},
    author={Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    note={\url{http://www.sdss.org/dr12/}},
    note = {Accessed: 2017-07-30},
}

% From SDSS Homepage & per Request

@article{sdss3spec,
    title={{SDSS}-III: Massive spectroscopic surveys of the distant universe, the Milky Way, and extra-solar planetary systems},
    author={Eisenstein, Daniel J and Weinberg, David H and Agol, Eric and Aihara, Hiroaki and Prieto, Carlos Allende and Anderson, Scott F and Arns, James A and Aubourg, {\'E}ric and Bailey, Stephen and Balbinot, Eduardo and others},
    journal={The Astronomical Journal},
    volume={142},
    number={3},
    pages={72},
    year={2011},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}


@article{sdssboss,
    title={The {SDSS}-IV extended baryon oscillation spectroscopic survey: Overview and early data},
    author={Dawson, Kyle S and Kneib, Jean-Paul and Percival, Will J and Alam, Shadab and Albareti, Franco D and Anderson, Scott F and Armengaud, Eric and Aubourg, {\'E}ric and Bailey, Stephen and Bautista, Julian E and others},
    journal={The Astronomical Journal},
    volume={151},
    number={2},
    pages={44},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}

@article{sdss2spec,
    title={The sloan digital sky survey: Technical summary},
    author={York, Donald G and Adelman, J and Anderson Jr, John E and Anderson, Scott F and Annis, James and Bahcall, Neta A and Bakken, JA and Barkhouser, Robert and Bastian, Steven and Berman, Eileen and others},
    journal={The Astronomical Journal},
    volume={120},
    number={3},
    pages={1579},
    year={2000},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}

@article{sdssscope,
    title={The 2.5 m telescope of the sloan digital sky survey},
    author={Gunn, James E and Siegmund, Walter A and Mannery, Edward J and Owen, Russell E and Hull, Charles L and Leger, R French and Carey, Larry N and Knapp, Gillian R and York, Donald G and Boroski, William N and others},
    journal={The Astronomical Journal},
    volume={131},
    number={4},
    pages={2332},
    year={2006},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}

% From Instructions (USED)


@article{bochanski,
    title={Low-mass dwarf template spectra from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    author={Bochanski, John J and West, Andrew A and Hawley, Suzanne L and Covey, Kevin R},
    journal={The Astronomical Journal},
    volume={133},
    number={2},
    pages={531},
    year={2007},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}

@article{pei1992,
    title={Interstellar dust from the Milky Way to the Magellanic Clouds},
    author={Pei, Yichuan C},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
    volume={395},
    pages={130--139},
    year={1992},
}

@article{meusinger2012unusual,
    title={Unusual quasars from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey selected by means of Kohonen self-organising maps},
    author={Meusinger, Helmut and Schalldach, P and Scholz, R-D and Newholm, M and de Hoon, A and Kaminsky, B and others},
    journal={Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
    volume={541},
    pages={A77},
    year={2012},
    publisher={EDP Sciences},
}

@article{meusinger2014large,
    title={A large sample of Kohonen-selected {SDSS} quasars with weak emission lines: selection effects and statistical properties},
    author={Meusinger, Helmut and Balafkan, N},
    journal={Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
    volume={568},
    pages={A114},
    year={2014},
    publisher={EDP Sciences},
}

@article{meusinger2016broad,
    title={Broad-band spectral energy distribution of 3000 {\AA} break quasars from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey},
    author={Meusinger, Helmut and Schalldach, P and Mirhosseini, A and Pertermann, F},
    journal={Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
    volume={587},
    pages={A83},
    year={2016},
    publisher={EDP Sciences},
}

@article{kohonen2001self,
    title={Self-organizing maps},
    author={Kohonen, T},
    journal={Springer},
    year={2001},
}

@article{ferrario2003analysis,
    title={Analysis of new spectropolarimetric data of AR UMa},
    author={Ferrario, Lilia and Wickramasinghe, DT and Schmidt, Gary},
    journal={Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
    volume={338},
    number={2},
    pages={340--346},
    year={2003},
    publisher={Blackwell Science Ltd Oxford, UK},
}

% From Instructions (MIGHT BE USEFUL)

@article{fischer2001accretion,
    title={Accretion physics of AM Herculis binaries-I. Results from one-dimensional stationary radiation hydrodynamics},
    author={Fischer, A and Beuermann, K},
    journal={Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
    volume={373},
    number={1},
    pages={211--221},
    year={2001},
    publisher={EDP Sciences},
}

@article{schmidt2007two,
    title={Two additions to the new class of low accretion rate magnetic binaries},
    author={Schmidt, Gary D and Szkody, Paula and Henden, Arne and Anderson, Scott F and Lamb, Don Q and Margon, Bruce and Schneider, Donald P},
    journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
    volume={654},
    number={1},
    pages={521},
    year={2007},
    publisher={IOP Publishing},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

        \large\textbf{Analysis of M star Spectra with Cyclotron Bumps from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS)}

        \vspace{1.5cm}
            \normalsize A thesis presented for the degree of\\
            Bachelor of Science

            \vspace{0.8cm}

            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{university}

            University of Leipzig\\
            Faculty of Physics and Earth Sciences\\
            Institute of Theoretical Physics\\
            August 2017

        \vfill

        \begin{multicols}{2}

            \normalsize Candidate \\
            \textbf{Cheung Kwan Kiu}

            \columnbreak
            Thesis Advisor \\
            \textbf{Prof. Dr. Helmut Meusinger} \\
            Second Examiner\\
            \textbf{Prof. Dr. Jan Meijer }


        \end{multicols}

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Declaration of Authorship}
"I, Ken Cheung Kwan Kiu, declare that this thesis and the work presented in it are my own and have been generated by me as the result of my own original research.
Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed. I have acknowledged all main sources of help and information.

Furthermore, I certify that this research thesis or any part of it has not been previously submitted for a degree or any other qualification at the University of Leipzig or any other institution in Germany or abroad." \\
    \begin{multicols}{2}

        Signature

        \columnbreak

        Date

    \end{multicols}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
I would like to thank Professor Meusinger and Jorg for their tips and scientific assistance throughout the analysis, and TOPCAT and SPLAT developers for their amazing softwares.

Funding for the Sloan Digital Sky Survey IV has been provided by the Alfred P. Sloan Foundation, the U.S. Department of Energy Office of Science, and the Participating Institutions. SDSS-IV acknowledges
support and resources from the Center for High-Performance Computing at
the University of Utah. The SDSS website is www.sdss.org.

SDSS-IV is managed by the Astrophysical Research Consortium for the 
Participating Institutions of the SDSS Collaboration including the 
Brazilian Participation Group, the Carnegie Institution for Science, 
Carnegie Mellon University, the Chilean Participation Group, the French Participation Group, Harvard-Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics, 
Instituto de Astrof\'isica de Canarias, The Johns Hopkins University, 
Kavli Institute for the Physics and Mathematics of the Universe (IPMU) / 
University of Tokyo, Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory, 
Leibniz Institut f\"ur Astrophysik Potsdam (AIP),  
Max-Planck-Institut f\"ur Astronomie (MPIA Heidelberg), 
Max-Planck-Institut f\"ur Astrophysik (MPA Garching), 
Max-Planck-Institut f\"ur Extraterrestrische Physik (MPE), 
National Astronomical Observatories of China, New Mexico State University, 
New York University, University of Notre Dame, 
Observat\'ario Nacional / MCTI, The Ohio State University, 
Pennsylvania State University, Shanghai Astronomical Observatory, 
United Kingdom Participation Group,
Universidad Nacional Aut\'onoma de M\'exico, University of Arizona, 
University of Colorado Boulder, University of Oxford, University of Portsmouth, 
University of Utah, University of Virginia, University of Washington, University of Wisconsin, 
Vanderbilt University, and Yale University.

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

%\include{./Chapters/1.Introduction}
%\include{./Chapters/2.Scientific_Background}
%\include{./Chapters/3.Data}
%\include{./Chapters/4.Analysis_of_Spectra}
%\include{./Chapters/5.1.Results}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.1}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.2}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.3}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.4}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.5}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.6}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.7}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.8}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.9}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.10}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.11}
%\include{./Chapters/5.2.12}
%\include{./Chapters/5.3}
%\include{./Chapters/6.Summary}


\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}


%\include{./Chapters/8.Appendix}

\end{document}
```

and results in the following pdf:

[image: first page of bibliography]

Comment: Thanks. This is why I hate coding :/ these stupid commas.....