# Bulk Comment Shortcut in `.bib` File Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I know there is one but googling has not helped. Anyone knows how to comment multiple lines in `.bib` file in overleaf?

For the `.tex` file, I simply highlight the lines and press `Ctrl + /`. This shortcut seems to be mapped to the usual bulk highlighting `Ctrl + A` in the bib file.
Thanks.

Comment: bibtex doesn't have comments https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/comments-in-bibtex